# How to create a custom control in code-behind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have an issue with creating custom controls in wpf. I always intend to create custom controls completely in code-behind in case I need to extend them.

The issue is when I add them in the xaml they are editable. I don't know how to explain but when I click on them, I can write into them. I think it's the way I'm writing my custom controls. Here's a sample code.

```
public class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        var button = new Button();

        this.Content = button;    // I always assign the root element to the Content property of the UserControl. I think this is the case
    }
}
```

As I said when I add MyCustomControl in Xaml part, it works totally fine but when I click on it (again in xaml part) it is editable and I can write into it. What's my problem exactly?

[Edit] I added screen shots

[image: MyCustomControl in normal state]
[image: MyCustomControl when I click on and write down into it]

this is the code-behind

```
public class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Content = new Grid() { Background = Brushes.Red };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Sure. I added screenshots @samar.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you can just overwrite the `Content` property as it is not locked in any way.

You could add a delegate on the `Coerce` of the `Content` and check using a `bool` check whether it is your code which is editing the control or some external source.

How to do this?

First read these articles:

- [Dependency Property Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#override_or_subclass)
- [How to: Override Metadata for a Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754209%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then, use something like this:

```
Control.ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(YourControlName), new PropertyMetadata(null, null, yourCallback));
```

As another option, you could create the `Control` as `Template` (define the `Control.Template` inside the `Control`). In this way you don't have to depend on the `Content` property (It won't affect the template). You can even put in the passed in `Content` if you want, but you don't need to.

Comment: That's a nice idea. I understand what you mean however I do not know how to implement the part "Adding a delegate checking whether it  is your code or some external source." could you provide me a sample please?

Comment: @user3530012: Found some sources how to do this. See the updated answer.

Comment: Well the problem is that Content property is accessible from xaml. I've found a solution to hide a property from xaml part which is to use EditorBrowsable attribute. but it doesn't work on inherited properties. I tried to override the property setter (by using the new keyword) but id didn't help either.

Comment: @user3530012: XAML relies on the DependencyProperties, so you are stuck there. I will put another option in.

Comment: @user3530012: Did my last update help you? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually I found out that even if I create a wpf usercontrol with XAML, I face the same problem. I mean as long as there is a Content property, it can be replaced by anything. It's just that a wpf usercontrol content property is not editable by a mouse click. Yes I overrided the metadada, even I created a new content property and set the setter to protected and even private. the result would be that content could not be updated anymore but the mouse click propblem was still out there. I mean when I clicked on the control it went to edit mod but it didn't allowed changing the content.

Comment: @user3530012: That sounds like the default behavior. Introducing a template would circumvent that `Content` will do anything relevant to your layout.

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks anyway Patrick. you tried and helped me a lot.

Comment: @user3530012: I am sorry I couldn't help you enough. Learned a lot though ;)